# Dados e parâmetros entre as Views

Tags: angularjs

Olá, eu estou criando um App com o IONIC Framework.
O front está completo. Fiz as transições de tela usando $stateProvider tranquilamente.

Mas preciso fazer as funcionalidades do APP e de forma geral **preciso de 2 coisas**

1) Passar parâmetros através do `href=""`

2) Executar determinadas funções ao clicar no botão de transição de tela e trazer a informação processada para a nova tela

Não consegui avançar porque não entendo o Angular produndamente e os muitos exemplos que vi por aí, não me esclareceram o suficiente. Isso é o que consegui até agora::

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="AppController as controller">
<ion-view title="Tela1"><ion-content>
   <a href="#/tela2" ng-click="controller.test1">
      <button class="estilo-botao">TESTE 1</button>
   </a>
   <a href="#/tela2" ng-click="controller.test2">
      <button class="estilo-botao">TESTE 2</button>
   </a>
</ion-content></ion-view>
```

...

**TELA2.HTML**

```
<ion-view title="Tela2"><ion-content>
   <input type="text" value="{{controller.parametro}}" />
</ion-content></ion-view>
```

**APP.JS**

```
...
app.config( function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider
  .state('tela2',{
        url:'/tela2',
        templateUrl:'views/tela2.html'
  })
...
app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    parametro = '';
    this.test1 = function(){
       alert('teste1');
       parametro = 'Um';
    };
    this.test2 = function(){
       alert('teste2');
       parametro = 'Dois';
    };
}]);
```

Eu já tentei um monte de coisas diferentes, essa foi a última. Já se tornou uma roleta russa.

Eu não entendi como funcionam os controles e o uso de **$scope**. Já vi exemplos usando **factory** e **service**, até o mini-curso do *CodeSchool* não me ajudou.

Alguém pode dar uma luz sobre o assunto?

Comment: Quando voce faz uma aplicação com templates para diferentes visualizações (Views/Templates) na mesma pagina (Single Page Application) por definição no angular não há necessidade de passagem de parâmetros pelo href. Toda comunicação se dá através de eventos que seus controllers disparam e capturam respectivamente... é uma mudança de paradigma considerável.

Comment: Entendi Rogerio. 
Eu encontrei um amigo que me explicou um pouco mais.

Eu agora estou esbarrando no MVC, porque a lógica (sem experiência) é meio confusa pra mim.

Estou estudando controllers, factory e services pra aplicar melhor. Muito obrigado!! :D :D